# Javascript Stop Propagation

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to figure out how to get an index of a dynamically created element so that I can write a function to delete it (splice).

I have figured out how to get the index really manually, but the problem is that I am getting Propagation from my event delegation and I am not sure how to stop it.

I have tried putting stopPropagation(), preventDefault(), stopImmediatePropagation() at various points within the function and have spent the last hour reading around online trying to figure out how to stop it. I even tried setting the e.bubble to false with no avail.

Could someone point me in the right direction here? Im sure its my inexperience but I am just out of ideas as of now.

```js
// Title of Question Set
const title = document.querySelector(".input_title-input");

// Array of Questions
const questions = [];
let chosen = [];

// Selected Question
let qChosen = [];

// Toggles if a new question is selected
let toggle = 0;

// Selecting Inputs and Button
let question = document.querySelector(".input_question-input");
let answer = document.querySelector(".input_answer-input");
let submit = document.querySelector(".input_submit-button");
let display = document.querySelector(".input_display");
let card = document.querySelector(".card_container");
let start = document.querySelector(".input_start-btn");
let guessInput = document.querySelector(".guess_input");
let submitGuess = document.querySelector(".submitGuess");
let nextQuestion = document.querySelector(".nextQuestion");

// Select all display items
let displayItems = document.getElementsByClassName("input_display-item");

// Select P quiz card values
let cardQuestion = document.querySelector(".quiz_question");
let cardAnswer = document.querySelector(".quiz_answer");

// Event Listener on Submit Button for Display Items Idividually
submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (question.value === "") {
        question.classList.toggle("error");
        answer.classList.toggle("error");
    } else {
        createObj();

        let trashCan = createDisplayItem();
        trashCan.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            console.log(this.parentNode);
            console.log(questions);
            console.log(e);
            this.parentNode.remove();
        });
        inputReset();
        toggle = questions.length;
        start.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
});

start.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    generateCard();
});

// Event Listener to test if guess is correct
submitGuess.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (guessInput.value.toLowerCase() === qChosen.answer.toLowerCase()) {
        card.classList.toggle("flip");
        submitGuess.disabled = true;
    } else {
        console.log("wrong or not working");
    }
});

nextQuestion.addEventListener("click", function() {
    card.classList.toggle("flip");
    submitGuess.disabled = false;
    setTimeout(generateCard, 1000);
});

// Create The object for inclusion to array
function createObj() {
    let obj = {};
    obj.question = question.value;
    obj.answer = answer.value;
    questions.push(obj);
}

// Resets inputs to blank after submit
function inputReset() {
    question.value = "";
    answer.value = "";
    if (question.classList.contains("error")) {
        question.classList.toggle("error");
        answer.classList.toggle("error");
    }
}

// Creates Each Display Item
function createDisplayItem() {
    // Create new Div
    let newUl = document.createElement("ul");

    // Create Li and Image Elements
    let liQuestion = document.createElement("li");
    let liAnswer = document.createElement("li");
    let trashCan = document.createElement("img");

    // Set img src
    trashCan.src = "../assets/trash.svg";

    // Set classes
    newUl.className = "input_display-item";
    liQuestion.className = "input_display-question";
    liAnswer.className = "input_display-answer";
    trashCan.className = "input_display-delete";

    // Set LI textContent
    liQuestion.textContent = question.value;
    liAnswer.textContent = answer.value;

    // Append Children
    display.appendChild(newUl);
    newUl.appendChild(liQuestion);
    newUl.appendChild(liAnswer);
    return newUl.appendChild(trashCan);
}

//Generating Card Information per question
function generateCard() {
    random();
    if (toggle < 0) {
        cardQuestion.textContent = "There are no more questions left";
        cardAnswer.textContent = "There are no more questions left";
    } else {
        cardQuestion.textContent = qChosen.question;
        cardAnswer.textContent = qChosen.answer;
    }
}

// Choses a random value for the selection set
function random() {
    if (questions.length === 0) {
        toggle = -1;
    } else {
        let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
        chosen = questions.splice(num, 1).concat(chosen);
        qChosen = chosen[0];
    }
}

// Notes
// I need to create a function that upon submit of a guess, checks its value against the answer textContent.
// I will likely need to make the text lowercase for the check to just make sure that they match exactly and that a capital letter wont create a false when its true.
```

```css
/** Variables
 ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/** Reset
 ---------------------------------------------------------*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit; }

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%; }

body {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #bdbdc7; }

/** Primary Container
 ---------------------------------------------------------*/
.container {
  max-width: 180rem;
  display: flex; }

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; }

.visible {
  visibility: hidden; }

/** Input Section
 ---------------------------------------------------------*/
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  line-height: 2rem; }

.input {
  width: 40rem;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column; }
  .input_title {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; }
    .input_title-label {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center; }
    .input_title-input {
      padding: 0.5rem; }
  .input_question {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; }
    .input_question-label {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center; }
    .input_question-input {
      padding: 0.5rem; }
  .input_answer {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; }
    .input_answer-label {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center; }
    .input_answer-input {
      padding: 0.5rem; }
  .input_question-input.error, .input_answer-input.error {
    border: 2px red solid; }
  .input_submit {
    width: 100%; }
    .input_submit-button {
      margin-top: 1rem;
      padding: 0 1.5rem; }
  .input_start {
    width: 100%; }
  .input_display {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 2rem 0 1rem 0; }
    .input_display-item {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      padding: .2rem 2rem;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 1rem;
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center; }
    .input_display-item:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #aaa;
      border-radius: 1rem; }
    .input_display-delete {
      height: 1.8rem;
      width: 1.8rem; }

.input :not(.input_display) div {
  padding-bottom: 2rem; }

/** Quiz Card
 ---------------------------------------------------------*/
.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%; }
  .card_container {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 1000px;
    width: 60rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer; }
    .card_container .front {
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
      transform-style: preserve-3d; }
      .card_container .front:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        opacity: 0.6;
        background-color: #000;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        border-radius: 10px; }
    .card_container .back {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #cedce7;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #dedce7 0%, #596a72 100%);
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      transform-style: preserve-3d; }
    .card_container .front,
    .card_container .back {
      background-color: red;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
      transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      text-align: center;
      min-height: 500px;
      height: auto;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 1.5rem; }

.flip {
  transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1); }
  .flip .back {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d; }
  .flip .front {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d; }

.inner {
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  perspective: inherit;
  z-index: 2; }

.front .inner p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative; }

.card_container-guess {
  padding-top: 2rem; }
  .card_container-guess .guess_input {
    width: 2rem;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55), 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #666;
    opacity: 0.6; }
    .card_container-guess .guess_input:hover, .card_container-guess .guess_input:focus {
      opacity: .8;
      color: #08c;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), inset 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }

.btnNew {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 12rem;
  margin: 1.5rem 3rem 1rem 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f4f1ee, #fff);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 30px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0px 4px 1px 1px white, inset 0px -3px 1px 1px rgba(204, 198, 197, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .1s linear;
  outline: none; }

.btnNew:after {
  color: #e9e6e4;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px #bdb5b4, 1px 1px 1px white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 3rem; }

.btnNew:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #f4f1ee);
  color: #0088cc; }

.btnNew:active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #efedec, #f7f4f4);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset opx -3px 1px 1px rgba(204, 198, 197, 0.5);
  outline: none; }

.btnNew:active:after {
  color: #dbd2d2;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px #bdb5b4, 0px 1px 1px white;
  outline: none; }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Flash</title>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section class="input">
            <div class="input_title">
                <label class="input_title-label" for="title">Enter a Title</label>
                <input class="input_title-input" id="title" type="text" placeholder="List of Towels">
            </div>

            <div class="input_question">
                <label class="input_question-label" for="question">Enter a Question</label>
                <input class="input_question-input" id="question" type="text" placeholder="What is 42?">
            </div>

            <div class="input_answer">
                <label class="input_answer-label" for="answer">Enter an Answer</label>
                <input class="input_answer-input" id="answer" type="text" placeholder="The Meaning Life, Universe, and Everything">
            </div>

            <div class="input_submit flex">
                <button class="input_submit-button btnNew">Submit</button>
            </div>

            <div class="input_display"></div>

            <div class="input_start flex">
                <button type="button" class="input_start-btn btnNew" disabled>Start Quiz</button>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="card">
            <div class="card_container">
                <div class="front">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <p class="quiz_question">Question</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="back">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <p class="quiz_answer">Answer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card_container-guess">
                    <input type="text" class="guess_input">
                    <button class="submitGuess btnNew">Submit Guess</button>
                    <button class="nextQuestion btnNew">Next Question</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>


    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Were you calling stopPropagation on the event object?

Comment: Have you tried using `return false;` to stop propogation?

Comment: Each of those at random times I was using e.[insert function] to add them in yes. I even moved them around the function thinking maybe I just had them out of order perhaps (inside of loop, beginning of loop, end of loop, before loop initiated, after loop initiated etc).

Comment: What behavior are you trying to prevent?

Comment: I just tried     return false; and I am getting the same results on my console.logs.

Comment: My apologies. I am basically trying to get 1 result so I can get access to the index of each click. So click first element, index = 0, second element index = 1 etc. I am wanting to figure out how to delete an item from the list.

Comment: It looks to me like you're just printing every index of the parent element, by stopping propagation do you mean you want to print just the index of the element you clicked on?

Comment: yes that would be correct. I am trying to use splice to delete, which requires (i believe) for me to know the index of the item in the array I want to delete. 

I admit I know little and am still learning js, so I might be doing something very simple wrong here as well.

Comment: You need some way to identify the children, maybe set the id to something like `child-1` etc, and then you can extract the index from the id.  Propagation is the event bubbling up to the parent, but you aren't listening for clicks on the parent that I can tell, so that isn't the issue here. You're just looping over every index of the parent and printing it. So you need to stop the loop (or really not use the loop in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wanting to figure out how to delete an item from the list

How about we change the last line of the function `createDisplayItem` to ..

```
function createDisplayItem(){
    ...
    return newUl.appendChild(trashCan) // Added return
}
```

Now, you have an instance of the newly created *trash can* element being returned to the calling code, so now all we have to do is add a click event to this specific trash can element and let it delete its parent `ul` ..

```
submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
    ...
    let trashCan = createDisplayItem();
    trashCan.addEventListener('click', function(){
        confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')
        && this.parentNode.remove()
    })
    ...
});
```

So, since now in this code, each trash can takes care of its own parent element, you do not have to worry about finding the index from the parent `display` element anymore.

Comment: This solved all my issues as well as introduced me to a new function. I had never even knew that confirm() was a thing. I actually had to look it up to see if you were just telling me to write something there to confirm or if that was what you meant! Thanks again!

edit: Would it be possible to replace the confirm() thought with a custom built modal instead? Just curious if calling another function would mess things up (or if its possible to change the CSS to the confirm window otherwise?)?

Comment: @CraigMenne Sure, a custom modal would work too. A `confirm` pauses the execution so we can just write it as a synchronous statement, but for your custom CSS based modal, you would need something like callbacks (or promises), like how [jQueryUI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) works. (See the `buttons` property.)

Comment: I wonder if you could offer some advice as I find myself in a similar situation after making a bunch of changes to this. I basically redid the array to now be an array of objects. After some work, realized I couldnt easily get a random question/answer pair using two seperate arrays. 

Now though, I realize that when I use the trashcan to delete an item, it removes it from display but does not remove it from the questions array? I am unsure what my changes messed up, as I believe it did use to remove it from the array as well. 

I updated the code above to the new. Could you have a look?

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle and provide a link .. @CraigMenne

Comment: @CraigMenne One way is to set the index while creating the trashCan, like `trashCan.dataset.index = questions.length - 1`, then inside the trashCan's click handler, you can splice the questions array like `questions.splice(this.dataset.index, 1)`.

Comment: Not sure I understand the first portion here. You mean to create it in my createDisplayItem()? Or do you mean right above the event listener as part of the submit? 
My apologies, ive not really ever used the dataset attribute before and not sure how it works. (mdn dont show it being used to set index)

**edit** meant let trashCan .... then trashCan.dataset ...

Comment: @CraigMenne Please see line `41` and `46` on [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojtpmu9s/1/).